# Asp.net iis web application (example.com/sub/) - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have main iis asp.net site (example.com). I add asp.net iis web application (example.com/sub/). Main site (example.com) works fine but (example.com/sub/) shows error

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is invalid.

```
 <section name="pages"
 type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection,
 System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
```

P.S. (example.com) and (example.com/sub/) have different "4.0 Intregrated" applications pools

Comment: what if you add as a different app? so not under the default web site

Comment: i want example.com and example.com/sub instead of example.com and sub.example.com. IIS Web application instead of virtual directory allows different application pools. May be problem with web.config inheritance from example.com to example.com/sub

Comment: and i do not have problem with simple html files in example.com/sub iis asp.net web application